# Core Data Predicate SQL Unable to Parse

Tags: ios, sql, swift, core-data

I've been banging my head on getting my filtering statement to work. I've tried a bunch of things (as you can see in my commented code).  What I am trying to do is do a search when the user is typing - searches customerObject.firstName, customerObject.lastName, and the title - if the phrase is in any of these show those results.  .lastName and .firstName are properties of the customerObject.

```
class func searchContainsPredicateEstimateInvoice(searchString: String, existingPredicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> NSPredicate
    {
        var words = searchString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        var predicateList = [NSPredicate]()
        for word in words
        {
            if count(word) > 0
            {
                var str = NSString(format: "SUBQUERY(%@, $f, $f.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR SUBQUERY(%@, $l, $l.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@)", "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)","\(USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)" ,word, "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)", "\(USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)", word, ESTIMATE_NAME_KEY, word)
                println(str)
                var pred = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(%@, $f, $f.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR SUBQUERY(%@, $l, $l.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@)", "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)","\(USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)" ,word, "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)", "\(USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)", word, ESTIMATE_NAME_KEY, word)

                //var pred = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(customerObject, $f, $f.firstName CONTAINS[cd] W).@count > 0")
                //var pred = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(customerObject, $g, $g.firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@).@count > 0", word)
                //var str = NSString(format: "SUBQUERY(%@, $f, $f.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR SUBQUERY(%@, $l, $l.%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@)", "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)","\(USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)" ,word, "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)", "\(USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)", word, ESTIMATE_NAME_KEY, word)
                predicateList.append(pred)
            }
        }

        if existingPredicate != nil
        {
            predicateList.append(existingPredicate!)
        }

        return NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: predicateList)

    }
    //var pred = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(%K, $f, $f.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR SUBQUERY(%K, $l, $l.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (%K CONTAINS[cd] %@)", "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)","\(USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)" ,word, "\(CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY)", "\(USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY)", word, ESTIMATE_NAME_KEY, word)
```

This is the actual value of what appears on the log:

```
SUBQUERY(customerObject, $f, $f.firstName CONTAINS[cd] W) OR SUBQUERY(customerObject, $l, $l.lastName CONTAINS[cd] W) OR (name CONTAINS[cd] W)
```

Data model:
[image]

Comment: Is "customerObject" a relationship in your entity? To-one or to-many? A screenshot of the Core Data model might be useful.

Comment: Didn't realize relationships mattered for a query. So yeah - customerObject is a different Core Data entity that an Estimate holds a reference to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your predicate creation:

- SUBQUERY is used only in conjunction with to-many relationships (and even
  then not always needed).
- *Never* use `NSString(format:)` to create predicates. The escaping and 
  quoting rules between string format strings and predicate format strings
  are too different.
- Use `%K` for key path substitution, not `%@`.

The predicate should therefore be something like

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@ OR %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@",
    CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY, USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY, word,
    CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY, USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY, word)
```

assuming that CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY is the name of a to-one relationship,
and USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY/USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY are attributes
of the target entity.

Comment: That did the trick: ```let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@ OR %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@ OR %K CONTAINS[c] %@",CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY, USER_LAST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY,word, CUSTOMER_OBJECT_KEY, USER_FIRST_NAME_LOCAL_KEY, word, ESTIMATE_NAME_KEY, word)```